# Is it possible to add a shortcut in Google Chrome that points to a sub folder

Tags: angular, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, shortcut

I have an Angular PWA deployed to a sub folder like this

*https://mywebsite.com/fileshare/app/test*

I would like to add a shortcut using Google Chrome but ran into an unexpected problem.

The shortcut that is generated will point to the root of the website *https://mywebsite.com*

Does someone out there know if or how this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possible. You need to give two property for that as below. Update your `manifest.json` file.

```
"start_url": "/fileshare/app/test",
"scope": "/fileshare/app/test"
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! It didn't work first but maybe it was related to caching issues.